# How tag automatically only some particular objects?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, enumerate, itemize, tags

Sometime ago I just started writing into doc format some Abstract Algebra notes but unfortunately I have needed frequently to put a lemma, a proposition or a theorem in the middle of document so that I had more times manually change the tag of many propositions: so today I decided to rewrite the notes into LateX hoping I could create an enumeration for tag automatically only what I need and so I started to search on net but I did not find anything and so I thought to ask help here. So, could someone explain how tag automatically only some particular objects so that it is possibile to modify always the document into the middle without adjusting manually the tag numbers? For exemplify let's we consider the following text:

Prop

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
   \begin{center}
      \Large\textbf{Note di Algebra}\\
   \end{center}
   \vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
\end{titlepage}

Un’applicazione $\bot$ del prodotto $Y\times X$ di due insiemi non vuoti $Y$ e $X$ nel secondo fattore $X$ si dice operazione binaria esterna a $X$ con dominio di operatori $Y$ mentre se $X$ e $Y$ sono eguali si dice ch’è un’operazione binaria in $X$ o semplicemente un’operazione in $X$ e in particolare per ogni coppia $(x_1,x_2)$ di elementi di $X$ si suole porre
\begin{equation}
    x_1\bot x_2:=\bot(x_1,x_2)
\end{equation}
sicché con tal convenzione si suole dire che l’operazione ⊥ è associativa allorché per qualsisia terna $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ di elementi di $X$ sussista l’eguaglianza
\begin{equation}
    (x_1\bot x_2)\bot x_3=x_1\bot (x_2\bot x_3)
\end{equation}
mentre si dice commutativa allorché per ogni coppia $(x_1,x_2)$ di elementi di $X$ sussista l’eguaglianza
\begin{equation}
    x_1\bot x_2=x_2\bot x_1
\end{equation}
inoltre, se $\bot$ non è commutativa ma $x_1$ e $x_2$ sono tali da verificare la precedente eguaglianza indi si dice ch’essi sono commutabili o permutabili rispetto $\bot$. Dunque, a scopo esemplificativo, osserviamo che per ogni funzione $\Phi$ di $\mathscr P(X)$ in X la posizione
$$
x_1\bot_\Phi x_2:=\Phi\big(\{x_1,x_2\}\big)
$$
con $x_1$ e $x_2$ in X definisce un’operazione in $X$ la quale è chiaramente commutativa ma in generale non associativa mentre una qualsiasi proiezione di $X\times X$ definisce un’operazione associativa ma non commutativa e infine una qualsiasi funzione costante di $X\times X$ in $X$ definisce un’operazione associativa e commutativa.
Ora stante gli assiomi di \boldsymbol{ZF} osserviamo che $\bot$ è un elemento di $X^(X\times X)$ sicché se i medesimi garantiscono che l’insieme $\mathscr P(X)\times X^(X\times X)$ esista allora diciamo che la coppia $(X,\bot)$ di $\mathscr P(X)\times X^(X\times X)$ è un gruppoide (o magma) con sostegno X e in particolare diciamo ch’essa è un semigruppo allorché l’operazione $\bot$ sia associativa nonché diciamo ch’è un semigruppo abeliano allorché l’operazione $\bot$ sia pure commutativa: precisiamo che più in generale alcuni autori sogliono chiamare struttura algebrica un qualsiasi elemento di $\mathscr P(X)\times\prod_{i\in n}X^(X_i^* )$  con $n$ in $\omega_+$ laddove $X_i^*$ con $i$ in $n$ è un prodotto cartesiano di due fattori uno dei quali sia $X$.
Ad ogni modo, per pura praticità poniamo
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal F(X^n,X):=X^{X^n}
\end{equation}
con $n$ in $\omega$ sicché dimostriamo il seguente fondamentale risultato.\\

Teorema 0 – di caratterizzazione dell’associatività

\end{document}
```

I would like to put $0$ automatically so that if one day I have to put a theorem before that I call "Teorema 0" then this last would labell as "Teorema 1" automatically:so how do it? could someone help me, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you almost never need to refer to explicit numbers in latex. sections theorems, equations etc are numbered automatically and any references to them pick up the right number. If that is not happening you have an error in your code but have not given enough information for us to correct your code.

Comment: For exemplify how can I write

(Proposition  - $n$)

where $n\in\Bbb N$ is put automatically?

Comment: Can you please put some simple code to illustrate your problem? It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: use `\label{anything}`  in the proposition then use `Proposition~\ref{anything}`

Comment: see https://www.learnlatex.org/it/lesson-09

Comment: @MS-SPO Unfortunately I cannot put any code because I have to copy the notes and so I thought to ask before how tag the proposition as I do into the example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is possible to use label even for enumerate a formula and not only for quote it?

Comment: I can not guess what you mean, the equation or proposition will be automatically numbered `\ref` allows you to reference that. As you edit the document the number may change but they will change together you never need to manually re-number. If you need more help make a small  but complete example in your question that does not work as you expect

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro, are you aware of https://ctan.org/topic/maths-theorem , e.g. `theorem` or the ams-package? As David indicated, when you work with such environments you hardly ever have to care about numbering: Latex uses adequate counters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did what you requires.

Comment: just like equations  theorems should be `\begin{theorem}...` and numbered automatically, not explicit text like `Teorema 0 `  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cnewtheorem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perfect: your suggestion was useful. Thanks very much for your assistance. :-)

Comment: I guess it should be `\textbf{ZF}`, not `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: @egreg You are right: thanks for the advice! :-)

Comment: It should also be `\mathbin{\bot}` and `X^(X\times X)` should be `X^{X\times X}`. Can you disclose the author of that text?

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the check. Well, I can say you that I am the author: I am writing a personal notes summarizing what I studied and explain it well with adding many passages to proofs or many example or counterexample. I hope I do not wrote bad things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a theorem with

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\setcounter{thm}{-1}% if you really?? want to start from 0
```

I also fixed:

```
Package eufrak Warning: The eufrak package is redundant if the amsfonts package
 is used on input line 36.

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ⊥ (U+22A5)
               not set up for use with LaTeX

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 53--55
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{calrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{bbold}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
% \usepackage{eufrak}
%\usepackage{yfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\setcounter{thm}{-1}% if you really?? want to start from 0
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1.0}}
   \begin{center}
      \Large\textbf{Note di Algebra}%\\
   \end{center}
   \vspace*{\stretch{2.0}}
\end{titlepage}

Un’applicazione $\bot$ del prodotto $Y\times X$ di due insiemi non vuoti $Y$ e $X$ nel secondo fattore $X$ si dice operazione binaria esterna a $X$ con dominio di operatori $Y$ mentre se $X$ e $Y$ sono eguali si dice ch’è un’operazione binaria in $X$ o semplicemente un’operazione in $X$ e in particolare per ogni coppia $(x_1,x_2)$ di elementi di $X$ si suole porre
\begin{equation}
% \coloneq
    x_1\bot x_2\coloneq\bot(x_1,x_2)
\end{equation}
% \bot
sicché con tal convenzione si suole dire che l’operazione $\bot$ è associativa allorché per qualsisia terna $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ di elementi di $X$ sussista l’eguaglianza
\begin{equation}
    (x_1\bot x_2)\bot x_3=x_1\bot (x_2\bot x_3)
\end{equation}
mentre si dice commutativa allorché per ogni coppia $(x_1,x_2)$ di elementi di $X$ sussista l’eguaglianza
\begin{equation}
    x_1\bot x_2=x_2\bot x_1
\end{equation}
inoltre, se $\bot$ non è commutativa ma $x_1$ e $x_2$ sono tali da verificare la precedente eguaglianza indi si dice ch’essi sono commutabili o permutabili rispetto $\bot$. Dunque, a scopo esemplificativo, osserviamo che per ogni funzione $\Phi$ di $\mathscr P(X)$ in X la posizione
% never $$
\[
%\coloneq \bigl
x_1\bot_\Phi x_2 \coloneq\Phi\bigl(\{x_1,x_2\}\bigr)
\]
con $x_1$ e $x_2$ in X definisce un’operazione in $X$ la quale è chiaramente commutativa ma in generale non associativa mentre una qualsiasi proiezione di $X\times X$ definisce un’operazione associativa ma non commutativa e infine una qualsiasi funzione costante di $X\times X$ in $X$ definisce un’operazione associativa e commutativa.
% math
Ora stante gli assiomi di $\boldsymbol{ZF}$ osserviamo che $\bot$ è un elemento di $X^(X\times X)$ sicché se i medesimi garantiscono che l’insieme $\mathscr P(X)\times X^(X\times X)$ esista allora diciamo che la coppia $(X,\bot)$ di $\mathscr P(X)\times X^(X\times X)$ è un gruppoide (o magma) con sostegno X e in particolare diciamo ch’essa è un semigruppo allorché l’operazione $\bot$ sia associativa nonché diciamo ch’è un semigruppo abeliano allorché l’operazione $\bot$ sia pure commutativa: precisiamo che più in generale alcuni autori sogliono chiamare struttura algebrica un qualsiasi elemento di $\mathscr P(X)\times\prod_{i\in n}X^(X_i^* )$  con $n$ in $\omega_+$ laddove $X_i^*$ con $i$ in $n$ è un prodotto cartesiano di due fattori uno dei quali sia $X$.
Ad ogni modo, per pura praticità poniamo
\begin{equation}
   \mathcal F(X^n,X):=X^{X^n}
\end{equation}
con $n$ in $\omega$ sicché dimostriamo il seguente fondamentale risultato.%\\

\begin{thm}
di caratterizzazione dell’associatività
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect: all celar now and so I upvoted and approved your answer. Thanks very much for the assistance! :-)